# Scan image for known components

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, scanning

Lets say Im having a screenshot of a chessgame. I am looking for a method to scan the screenshot for known components. Ie. how to find the pieces on the board and their position.

Preferable I would like to do this in .NET - anyone can direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a database with how the pieces look like you can use Cross Correlation to find them in the picture.

In one of my projects I am using Cross Correlation to find a known piece of sound in an audio file, you might want to check out [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound) on this topic. In the question I provided my solution. Read the accepted answer for some background.

Comment: +1 available in EMGU's C# port of OpenCV http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/OpenCV