# Using 2 MemoryStreams with CalcCrossCorrelation

Tags: .net, vb.net, ienumerable, memorystream

Based on this post: [Use convolution to find a reference audio sample in a continuous stream of sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound)

I´m trying to do the same, but I have 2 MemoryStreams and I need to find the first MemoryStream piece inside the second MemoryStream. Do you mind give me some direction how to convert those MemoryStream to IEnumerable(Of Double)? Or your approach it´s based on the file wav?

Comment: When you say you're "trying to do the same", are you talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound)?

Comment: Please provide a link or explanation for "CalcCrossCorrelation" as Google isn't turning up much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847570/use-convolution-to-find-a-reference-audio-sample-in-a-continuous-stream-of-sound